# Why is not working when i try to add a to a string to my array location

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm still learning JavaScript, and now I'm in the array chapter and I'm doing this project I have to ask the user for 5 names and stored and my array, then have to sort the names by the location in the array, so i could separed in odd and in even, then i have to add a lastname to the odds, and different last name to the even, but is that part that is not working any help ... THANKS

```
var numberfirstNames = 5;
var userMessage = " Please enter a first Name" ;
var secondArray = [];
var odd2 = [];
var even2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberfirstNames; i++) // loop 5 times  LOOL ASKING FOR "5" FIRST NAMES>> STORING IN NAMES   
{
    secondArray[i] = getFirstname();
    window.alert("second " + secondArray[i] );
}
for (var i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0)  // index is even
    {
        even2.push(secondArray[i]);
        for ( var i=0 ; i<even2.length; i++)
            even2[i]+=" Chavez"
    }
    else
    {
        odd2.push(secondArray[i]);
        for ( var i=0 ; i<odd2.length; i++)
            odd2[i]+=" McCain"
    }
}

document.write(" \n all the names: "+ secondArray+'<br>');
document.write(" \n even names: "+ even2+'<br>');
document.write(" \n odd names: "+ odd2+'<br>');
```

Comment: It's not very clear. Can you provide the input and output that you expect?

Comment: ok, so I expect that the user, enters 5 first names...
then with the 5 first name in my array the first names with position even add this last name "Chavez" and if is a odd position "McCain".

Comment: _but is that part that is not working_ how is it not working? do you get any error? Is output different from what you expect? describe the problem clearly

Comment: JavaScript has routines for sorting arrays, visit http://w3schools.com for help.

Comment: so I'm successful sorting the values of the array if is a odd or even position, but is making me a mess when a tried to add the last name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making a second loop that is unnecessary... the code

```
for ( var i=0 ; i<even2.length; i++)
```

and

```
for ( var i=0 ; i<odd2.length; i++)
```

should be simply removed.

You need to add first or last name only to last element added to `odd2` or `even2` and this can be done with:

```
 even2[even2.length-1]+=" Chavez"
```

and

```
 odd2[odd2.length-1]+=" McCain"
```

It is important to get used adding correct indentation because this kind of error is much easier to spot in the code when it is properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop again to add the specific last name. You can just prepend it while you are inserting it into the array like below.

```
var numberfirstNames = 5;
var userMessage = " Please enter a first Name";
var secondArray = [];
var odd2 = [];
var even2 = [];

// loop 5 times LOOP ASKING FOR "5" FIRST NAMES >> STORING IN NAMES
for (var i = 0; i < numberfirstNames; i++) {
    secondArray[i] = getFirstname();
    window.alert("second " + secondArray[i]);

    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        even2.push(secondArray[i] + " Chavez");
    } else {
        odd2.push(secondArray[i] + " McCain");
    }

}

document.write(" \n all the names: " + secondArray.join(",") + '<br>');
document.write(" \n even names: " + even2.join(",") + '<br>');
document.write(" \n odd names: " + odd2.join(",") + '<br>');
```